# What does Erl return when there are no line numbers?

Tags: error-handling, vb6, line-numbers

If a module has no line numbers, what will the `Erl` statement return when an error is caught?

Comment: @Deanna: I'm finding it hard to choose between yours and paxdiablo's answer.  If you can deal categorically with the effect of `Exit` and `Resume` statement on the `Erl` value I will accept your answer.

Comment: I can't without trying it :) Paxdiablo's answer is slightly clearer and easier to understand IMO.

Answer (score 6):

`Erl` will return 0 in a method without line numbers. If some of the lines have numbers then the `Erl` will return the number of the last executed line that has one.

Answer (score 4):

From memory, `Erl` holds the last line number encountered (or zero if none had been encountered) so that would be my guess. It's also reset back to zero for certain operations such as `exit something` and `resume something`.

But surely this would be easy to check with a piece of code like (untested):

```
42: x = 0
    on error goto err_bit
    y = 31415 / x
    exit
err_bit:
    msgbox (erl)
```

and trying different scenarios with the line numbers.